# validation in email and phone number and name

Tags: android, android-studio

Actually I want to validate email and phone no. I tried doing that still its not working for me .Its like there is no error in my code ..but the output which I am expecting after entering phone no. and email is not correct. while entering phone number it must contain 10 digits and for email   I have specified the regular expressions but still its like  for ex. if I enter "bchydfg" it is expecting the email without displaying my stoast message .Also I want that name should have more than 3 alphabets and less than 20 alphabets.Also when i click the register button it should display the toast msg that all the fields are compulsary to be filled.

this is my java code.

```
public class NewUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText phone;
    EditText usname;
    EditText passsword;
    Button register;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_user_login);


        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        usname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usname);
        passsword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passsword);
        register= (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);


        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String PHONENO =phone.getText().toString().trim();
                String username = usname.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = passsword.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                if (NAME.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(EMAIL.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter  email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter correct email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(PHONENO.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter correct phone number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(username.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(username.length()<8|| username.length()>15)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username must contain  atleast 8  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(password.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(password.length()<6|| password.length()>10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must contain 6  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                }
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it validates Email as well as Phone number. Hope its work for you its tested.

```
private void checkEmailAndPhone(String email, String phone){
    String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";
    String phonePattern = "(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}";

    if(email.matches(emailPattern)){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Correct Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(phone.matches(phonePattern)){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Correct Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wrong Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wrong Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```